# List of specific class names in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to flag class declarations so that later you can get a list of them flagged?

Or a way to get all classes starting with a certain string ?

Or all classes that are a subclass of a specific class?

Comment: What's wrong with using `grep` to search the source?  You have the source for all Python.  Why can't use simply use `grep` on those files?

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** in the following I assume Python 3.x. For Python 2.x, use [new style classes](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/), i.e. write `class T(object): pass` instead of `class T: pass`.

1. First, define some classes:

   ```
   >>> class T: pass
   ... 
   >>> class S: pass
   ... 
   >>> class U(T): pass
   ...
   ```
2. To get a list of classes defined in the current scope, iterate over the [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#globals) (or [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#locals)) and test whether they are an instance of [`type`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#type) (thus a class!) using [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#isinstance):

   ```
   >>> [n for n, o in globals().items() if isinstance(o, type)]
   ['S', 'U', 'T']
   ```
3. Use [`issubclass`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#issubclass) to restrict your search to the subclasses of a given class (in this case `T`):

   ```
   >>> [n for n, o in globals().items() if isinstance(o, type) and issubclass(o, (T,))]
   ['U', 'T']
   ```
4. You may want to omit `T` itself:

   ```
   >>> [n for n, o in globals().items() if o != T and isinstance(o, type) and issubclass(o, (T,))]
   ['U']
   ```
5. To get all classes starting with a certain string, call [`startswith`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) on the class name:

   ```
   >>> [n for n, o in globals().items() if n.startswith('T') and isinstance(o, type)]
   ['T']
   ```
6. To *flag* certain classes at creation, use a [class decorator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/)<sup>†</sup> to add an attribute, e.g. `__flagged__`:

   ```
   >>> def flag(cls):
   ...     cls.__flag__ = 'flagged'
   ...     return cls
   ... 
   >>> @flag
   ... class X: pass
   ... 
   >>> @flag
   ... class Y: pass
   ... 
   >>> class Z: pass
   ...
   ```
7. Now you can just select only those classed with the `__flag__` attribute:

   ```
   >>> [n for n, o in globals().items() if isinstance(o, type) and hasattr(o, '__flag__')]
   ['X', 'Y']
   ```

---

<sup>†</sup>: As [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) notes, class decorators are [new in Python 2.6](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3129-class-decorators).

Comment: bobince: yeah, it just dawned on me that it didn't work in 2.x because I forgot to use new style classes...

Comment: This all looks fine for Python 2.x too... class decorators are new in 2.6.

Comment: Hah, now it looks like I saw into the future and knew you were going to comment ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll probably use is subclass minus T solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use metaclasses to collect up the classes as they are defined:

```
class AllSeeingMetaClass(type):
    # This will be a list of all the classes that use us as a metaclass.
    the_classes = []

    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        # Invoked as new classes are defined.
        print "Defining %r" % classname
        new_class = type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict)
        meta.the_classes.append(new_class)
        return new_class


class MyBase(object):
    # A base class that pulls in our metaclass.
    __metaclass__ = AllSeeingMetaClass


class Cat(MyBase):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Dog(MyBase):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

print AllSeeingMetaClass.the_classes
```

prints:

```
Defining 'MyBase'
Defining 'Cat'
Defining 'Dog'
[<class '__main__.MyBase'>, <class '__main__.Cat'>, <class '__main__.Dog'>]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of subclasses of your class from within itself, use the __subclasses__ method from the parent class.

```
>>>class Parent(object):
...    pass
...
>>>class Child(Parent):
...    pass
...
>>>Parent.__subclasses__()
>>>[<class '__main__.Child'>]
```

Unfortunately there is a dearth of documentation on this method.